# Browser go back to active div in previous page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a list of button where once clicked, it will shows the respective div as below. And in the div, there is a few links that user can click, and once they clicked the link and go back, it will bring them back to the previous div instead of the first default div. Codes as below.

```html
<div class="tab">
    <a class="tablinks btn" href="#m0" id="t0">Item A</a>
    <a class="tablinks btn" href="#m1" id="t1">Item B</a>
    <a class="tablinks btn" href="#m2" id="t2">Item C</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tlist">
    <div id="m0" class="tdiv" style="display:block;">
    <a href="LinkA.html">LinkA</a></div>
    <div id="m1" class="tdiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="LinkB.html">LinkB</a></div>
    <div id="m2" class="tdiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="LinkC.html">LinkC</a></div>
    </div>
```

I have Javascript codes that will change the `display` from `none` to `block` when user clicked on the `Item`.

```js
document.getElementById("m0").style.display = "block";

document.getElementById("t"+i).addEventListener('click',divStyle.bind(this,"m"+i),false);

function divStyle(num) {
  var i,tdiv,tablinks;
  tdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("tdiv");

  for (i=0;i<tdiv.length;i++) {
    tdiv[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  
  for (i=0;i<tablinks.length;i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(num).style.display = "block";
  Event.className += "active";
}
```

```js
//print tab for Item
function printTab(itemnum) {  
  for (var y = 0; y < itemnum; y++) {    
    tabbtn = document.createElement("a");  
    tabbtn.classList.add("tablinks", "btn", "btn-secondary");  
    tabbtn.setAttribute("href", "#m" + y);  
    tabbtn.setAttribute("id", "t" + y);  

    if (y == 0) {   
      tabbtn.classList.add("tablinks", "btn", "btn-secondary", "active");  
    }  

    tabtxt = document.createTextNode("");  //print Item text here 
    tabbtn.appendChild(tabtxt);  
    document.getElementById("tab").appendChild(tabbtn);
  }

  //print div for Link
  function printLink(num) {

    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(); 

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {  
      moddiv = document.createElement("div");  
      moddiv.setAttribute("id", "m" + num);  
      moddiv.setAttribute("class", "tdiv");  
      moddiv.style.display = "none";  
      
      for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {   
          /*do something here and put link of each item*/    
      }    
            
    moddiv.appendChild(docFrag);  
    document.getElementById("tlist").appendChild(moddiv);  
}
```

The problem I have now is that when LinkC is clicked, and user then pressed Back button in the browser, browser goes back to the link of the previous specific div, for example, `page.html#m2` but shows `div m0`. I guess this is because I already set `document.getElementById("m0").style.display = "block";` by default so it will always go to `div m0` but is there other way to make sure the browser will go back to the previous specific div chosen?

My google finding shows people suggesting `history.back()` but that means I need to create a Back button but I do not want that. I am sure this is not a complicated issue but I can't think anymore on how to solve this.
Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Update: I tried to use `history.back()` and created a button but this also is not working as it still display `div m0`. :(

Update #2: Tried this on Firefox and it is working though. Is there another way to make sure it can work for different browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the bellow code :

```html
<div class="tab">
    <a class="tablinks btn active" href="#m0" id="t0">Item A</a>
    <a class="tablinks btn" href="#m1" id="t1">Item B</a>
    <a class="tablinks btn" href="#m2" id="t2">Item C</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="tlist">
    <div id="m0" class="tdiv" style="display:block;">
    <a href="LinkA.html">LinkA</a></div>
    <div id="m1" class="tdiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="LinkB.html">LinkB</a></div>
    <div id="m2" class="tdiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="LinkC.html">LinkC</a></div>
</div>


<style>
    
    a{color:#333;text-decoration: none;background: #eee;border: 1px solid #333;border-radius:5px;padding:3px;}    
    .active{color:blue;background: #ccc;}

</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
    
   var tabSelect=(url)=>{
        console.log(url);
        let hs = url.split('#')[1]||'m0',ts = hs.split('m').join('t');        
        if(hs!=''){
            let tabcs = document.getElementsByClassName('tdiv');
            for(let tabc of tabcs){if(tabc.id){tabc.style.display='none';}}
            let tabhs = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
            for(let tabh of tabhs){if(tabh.id){tabh.className="tablinks btn"}}
            let c = document.getElementById(hs);
            if(c){c.style.display = 'block';document.getElementById(ts).className="tablinks btn active"}
        }
    }

     window.onhashchange=(i)=>{tabSelect(i.newURL);}
     window.onload=()=>{tabSelect(location.href);}

</script>
```

Hope you will be fine with this code.

Comment: do you mean to put the js code in the function `divStyle`?

Comment: You can add this javascript code after the HTML code or on included JS file. it will work anywhere.

Comment: Tried it but no change. My problem is when user clicked and opened LinkC.html, and when they go back to the previous page it shows the default div m0 eventhough the URL is `page.html#m2`

Comment: Just noticed `onhashchange` only works if it is in the same page since it only detects anchor of the url right?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please copy the full code and let me know if it works or not. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not working though. I even tried on plunker and it is still not working. Can you explain what do you mean by your code? I think `onhashchange` won't be able to change anything since it is not the same page unless I make the LinkC.html to load on the same page Ithink hmm

Comment: I have created a live example. Please check this [live example](https://dev.efoli.com/test/tab.html) and let me know if working or not.

Comment: I think this should work. The live example you gave is exactly what I need. In my actual coding, `tablinks` and `tlist` is actually generated from the function in javascript where it is  depending on the value from a json file.

Comment: So according to my above code and function after your json file is read and rendered the html completely put this code: `tabSelect(location.href);`

Comment: But because of the default `window.onload()` above, it won't print both `tablinks` and `tdiv`. I have edited the post with the function I made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243440/discussion-between-kaixas-k-and-pran-paul).

Comment: It will be good for me if you upload your code to any live place(later you can remove it) and I will check and try to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Here it is https://plnkr.co/plunk/ebS29iiF9E3sBOKQ Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I found the solution! Your coding works well but I used `<body onload=getTab()>` to automatically run the main function which is why it keeps showing the default div. I moved `getTab()` under `window.onload()` and now it works. Thank you!